# How to retrieve values of a child by searching the other value of the child in the same parent

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase real-time database. So in the user node, it has all the user id and inside the user, id has all the user information(name, email, longitude, latitude, password). What I want to do is to query the database to check the name of the user if identical, if yes then I want to get the value of `longitude` and `latitude` from the same parent(user id).

[Here is my database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THv8F.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the latitude and longitude of a user who's name is for example `abc`, please try the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference userRef = rootRef.child("user");
Query queryByName = userRef.orderByChild("name").equalTo("anb");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            double latitude = ds.child("latitude").getValue(Double.class);
            double longitude = ds.child("longitude").getValue(Double.class);
            Log.d(TAG, latitude + ", " + longitude);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
queryByName.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The restul in your logcat will be:

```
3.077057, 101.590268
```

Comment: thank you very much, I will try it and let you know